# You were supposed to ask me something?

Tags: past-tense

> You were supposed to ask me something?

Could you please correct the above sentence? Can we use sentence like this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, you have to arrange this sentence as a question: normally we put the auxiliary verb **before** the subject to do it - in this case the auxiliary verb is the verb "to be":

> Were you supposed to ask me something?

Also, you may modify the pronoun "something", but it depends on the context from where this sentence comes from. If the speaker expects an affirmative answer from the hearer, then something can be used - though it is not rule at all. Otherwise, you should use anything, indeed is quite more common to use this indefinite pronoun in interrogative sentences.

In the end:

> Were you supposed to ask me anything?

Sounds better to me, I think.